# UI-router throw error as `Invalid state ref`, when adding link to `ui-sref'

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

for the following `route` :

```
.state('user', {
                url:'/user/:userId',
                templateUrl : 'app/views/pages/user/user.html',
                controller  : 'userController as user',
                required    : true,
                resolve     : {
                    userData : function( $q, api, $stateParams ){

                        console.log('hi', $stateParams)

                        var differed = $q.defer();

                        api.getUsers().then(function( data ){
                            differed.resolve( data.data );
                        });

                        return differed.promise;

                    }
                }
            })
```

I am calling from one of my html as like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users.usersData"><a ui-sref="user(userId:{user._id})">{{user.name}}</a></li>
```

But getting error as :

```
angular.js:13920 Error: [$parse:syntax] 

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=:&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=7&p3=userId:%7Buser._id%7D&p4=:%7Buser._id%7D
```

what is wrong with my code? any one help me here?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could create a plunker quickly.

Comment: this is one of part from my app, it's no so easy to create. still do you find any wrong stuff here? if you require any part of code, I am ready to post you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ui-sref

```
ui-sref="user(userId:{user._id})"
```

should be like

```
ui-sref="user({userId:user._id})"
```

what we pass is an **object** with property named `userId` and value coming from `user._id`: **`{userId:user._id}`**